# Swipe on mobile device (iPad Settings screen) always swipe on right half. How to perform Swipe in Left half

Tags: ios, mobile, ui-automation, appium-ios, seetest

I need to swipe on IPad settings screen. Ipad setting screen have options on left and based on option selected, You will get right half of screen.

Now with Swipe command in Seetest( A tool based on Appium) it always perform swipe in right half.
Is there a way to perform Swipe on left half?

I have used Swipe command.
Swipe(Direction, Offset, Time)

```
@Test
    public void testUntitled(){
        client.setDevice("<Device Name>");
        client.click("NATIVE", "xpath=//*[@text='General' and @class='UIAStaticText']", 0, 1);
        client.swipe("Down", 292, 603);
    }
```

Expected : Should swipe on left half.

Actual: It always swipe in right half.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code `seetest .elementSwipeWhileNotFound("NATIVE", "id=nav_drawer", "Down", 0, 2000, "NATIVE", "text=History", 0, 1000, 5, true)` This code would swipe inside the element 'id=nav_drawer' until it finds 'text=History'. You can find the detailed information [here](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/ElementSwipeWhileNotFound).